# persisted remember-me authentication after using custom filter

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I'm using Spring-Security 3.1.RELEASE within a Spring Roo environment. I've changed the login mechanism so that it works with JSON-Response. For that I've created two classes (scala) namely

```
class JsonSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
 override def onAuthenticationSuccess(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, authentication: Authentication) = {
  val responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);
  val out = responseWrapper.getWriter
  out.write("{success: true}")
  out.close
 }
}

@Repository class JsonEntryPoint extends AuthenticationEntryPoint {
 def commence(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, ae: AuthenticationException) = {
  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized")
 }
}
```

The entries in application-security.xml are as follows:

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="jsonAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
  <custom-filter ref="rememberMeFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>

  <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

  <intercept-url pattern="/backend/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</http>


<beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userServiceDb"/>
  <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="tokenRepository"/>
  <beans:property name="key" value="reservation" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
 <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="mySuccessHandler" />
  <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
  <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="email" />
  <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="JsonSuccessHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="jsonAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="JsonEntryPoint" />
```

Authentication is working fine, so I can successfully login and also concerning remember-me the data is stored successfully into the database (table persistent_logins). But when I restart the server the Session is as expected deleted and the remember me functionality should do its work. Unfortunately it fails with following log data:

```
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
17:19:15.867 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
17:19:15.875 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
17:19:15.875 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
17:19:15.877 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
17:19:15.878 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
17:19:15.878 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
17:19:15.878 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
17:19:15.879 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
17:19:15.879 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.r.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Remember-me cookie detected
17:19:15.895 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
17:19:15.895 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select username,series,token,last_used from persistent_logins where series = ?]
17:19:15.896 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
17:19:15.922 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
17:19:15.938 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.r.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Refreshing persistent login token for user 'physio1@physio-termin.at', series 'oLmZMQbnFsfyTziANriMKw=='
17:19:15.939 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
17:19:15.944 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [update persistent_logins set token = ?, last_used = ? where series = ?]
17:19:15.944 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
17:19:15.984 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
17:19:15.992 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
17:19:15.996 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
17:19:15.996 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select email username, password, isactive enabled from principal where email = ?]
17:19:15.996 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
17:19:16.001 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
17:19:16.013 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
17:19:16.013 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select p.email username, a.authority from principal p inner join principal_authority apa on p.id = apa.principal_id inner join authority a on a.id = apa.authorities_id where p.email = ?]
17:19:16.013 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
17:19:16.015 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
17:19:16.021 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.r.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Remember-me cookie accepted
17:19:16.036 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
17:19:16.042 [qtp1943091306-38] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.r.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as AuthenticationManager rejected Authentication returned by RememberMeServices: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@2fb6ff6b: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@d45302c2: Username: physio1@physio-termin.at; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_PHYSIOTHERAPEUT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_PHYSIOTHERAPEUT'; invalidating remember-me token
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:196) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:102) ~[spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

What am I missing? I dont't understand why the ProviderNotFoundException is thrown.

Comment: Please turn debug on (add line `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to log4j.properties) and post output of (not working) remember-me request here in your question.

Comment: The debug message says remember-me was not used because `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` was found, so it seems that's not a problem with remember-me. Can you post **full** debug output, beginning with normal login, session expiration and remember-me login attempt? Also please define more precisely what did you mean saying "Authentication is working fine, but the remember-me functionality not at all".

Comment: I've updated my original post since I made some progress in using the Persistent-Aproach with Jdbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done, authentication works OK, you forgot to add [`RememberMeAuthenticationProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.html). If you use security namespace to create AuthenticationManager, just add separate `<authentication-provider>` like here:

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref="yourRegularAuthenticationProvider" />
  <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="key" value="reservation" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing link. Just a last question. Is this somewhere documented or does one have to find it by looking into the source code?

Comment: It's documented [here in Remeber-Me chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me-impls) and [here in chapter about `AuthenticationProvider`s](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#core-services-authentication-manager) saying that _each provider is able to attempt authentication, or skip authentication by simply returning null. If all implementations return null, the `ProviderManager` will throw a `ProviderNotFoundException`_