# RememberMeAuthenticationFilter and Java Config: Custom implementation to override onSuccessfulAuthentication - how to do it in a clean way?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Providing an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` for a `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` breaks the filter chain, therefore I would like to override its `onSuccessfulAuthentication` method by providing a custom implementation of `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter`. But that seems to be quite complicated or elaborate when using simple Java Config.

Providing an `ApplicationEventPublisher` is not a solution if one needs access to `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse`.

I managed to do it, but it looks like a hack - is there a better way?

I've done it this way:

```java
http.rememberMe().addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<RememberMeAuthenticationFilter>() {

    @Override
    public <O extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O object) {

        RememberMeAuthenticationFilter newFilter = new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(
                (AuthenticationManager) getByReflection(object, "authenticationManager"),
                (RememberMeServices) getByReflection(object, "rememberMeServices")
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) {
                // business logic
            }
        };
        return (O) newFilter;
    }

    private <O extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter> Object getByReflection(O object, String name) {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(object.getClass(), name);
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        return ReflectionUtils.getField(field, object);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to implement a custom behavior when authentication process (with remember me feature) is success you can try:

## CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter

Define a new filter such as:

```
public class CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter {
  @Override
  protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authResult) {
    super.onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
    if (authResult != null) {
        // process post authentication logic here..
    }
  }
}
```

Set the customer filer in security chain:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/","/login*").permitAll()
    //...
  http
    .addFilter(rememberMeAuthenticationFilter())
    //...
}

@Bean
protected RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeAuthenticationFilter(){
    return new CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(),rememberMeServices());
}
```

Check [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java) in order to create your **(authenticationManager(),rememberMeServices()**

In the previous snippet, custom filter is just added. If does not works, you must research and find the exact Filter in the chain to insert your custom filter: addFilterBefore, addFilterAfter, addFilterAt.

Check this [add filter methods](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter#1-java-configuration)

Finally remove the default **http.rememberMe()** in order to use your own filter. Because the remember-me namespace element already inserts a RememberMeAuthenticationFilter so it will still take precedence over yours, since it comes before it in the filter chain.

## References

- https://github.com/DGYao/spring-boot-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springboot/web/WebSecurityConfigurer.java
- https://craftingjava.com/blog/user-management-remember-me-jwt-token/
- [How can I use a custom configured RememberMeAuthenticationFilter in spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432663/how-can-i-use-a-custom-configured-remembermeauthenticationfilter-in-spring-secur)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-remember-me
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter#1-java-configuration
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22668530/3957754
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me-impls
- [How can I use a custom configured RememberMeAuthenticationFilter in spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432663/how-can-i-use-a-custom-configured-remembermeauthenticationfilter-in-spring-secur/35306316)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html
- [persisted remember-me authentication after using custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525901/persisted-remember-me-authentication-after-using-custom-filter)
- https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-implement-remember-password-remember-me-for-java-web-application
- [Spring Security custom RememberMeAuthenticationFilter not getting fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663488/spring-security-custom-remembermeauthenticationfilter-not-getting-fired/22668530#22668530)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! I (already) know it's *possible* that way, but it would require much more code compared to the hack I presented above. The `RememberMeConfigurer` created by `http.rememberMe()` does so many complex things which I do not want to repeat. But probably there is no easy way to achieve that.